# WordPress import, how to get gallery images imported

Tags: wordpress, gallery

For a client of mine, I need to import posts from a second site. When using the default WP-Importer plugin, the gallery images are not imported. The reason is, that a gallery in WordPress is a shortcode like this:

```
[gallery ids="4001,4002,4003"]
```

Unfortunately, when importing attachments, these will not get imported with the same post_id as the original, so the images 4001, 4002 and 4003 become maybe 5601, 5602 and 5603.

Now I'm planning to work on a custom script, which will parse all post_content for all the imported posts, check the old thumbnail_id and replace it with the new one in the content.

I wonder if there might be an easier solution for this problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the [Duplicator plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/) to move installation, and you change and delete everything that is not needed anymore. But this option is the best if the new site is not live yet.

**Edited** 
What this plugin is doing is that it makes a copy of you whole site with database and files. And then you can install this plugin to the new site and run an import from the backup file the the Duplicator plugin did on the old site.

You can even filter out to only include `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta` from the database. And only export wp-upload directory

Comment: Thanks. I am familar with duplicator. The thing is, that it won't work, as the existing site has already data in the database (like products and orders) and need to get posts from another site. So duplicator would just try to import the posts with the given post_id and either fail (because these ids are already in use) or add it with a new ID which will not reflect the IDs in the gallery shortcode.